# Пробросить переменную в $.each()

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть следующий код:

```
$('#PROGRAMS .options > div').click(function(){
    var pid = this.value;
    $('#group .options > div').each(function(index, elem){
        console.log(pid);
    });
});
```

Из функции в `each()` переменная `pid` не видна. Как её туда пробросить?

Comment: Потому что ее значение - `undefined`, а у `div` нет никакого `value`? Вот этот код прекрасно срабатывает прямо на этой странице

    $('.question-body').click(function(){
        var pid = 123;
        $('.question-body').each(function(){
            console.log(pid);
        });
    });

Comment: В крайнем случае всегда можно использовать замыкание

    $('.question-body').click(function(){
        var pid = 123;
        var func = (function(vpid){
            return function(index, elem){
                console.log(vpid);
           }
        })(pid);
         $('.question-body').each(func);
    });

Но, насколько понимаю, обратная модификация переменной из функции получится только для объектов.

Comment: Вероятно утренний тупняк)) Надо `var pid = this.getAttribute('value')`

Comment: Больше похоже, что вы не понимаете разницу между свойством и атрибутом.